# Is this a Piezo Electric Buzzer?

Tags: pcb

Just wondering if someone could confirm to me whether this component is a Piezo Electric Buzzer.  I haven't seen them in this rectangular form factor before (rather than the more common circular one).  What brand / model, because a google search for "NAT-12" is coming up empty.  Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: It's a definite maybe .... [Square Piezo Buzzers](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/alarms-buzzers-and-sirens/157?s=N4IgjCBcoCwGxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDa4A7BQBwCcIhATAAxgsMiMDMbArB4xhde9Jr2rNmAuGwRMKYWhHmDqAirRgx1tCQNpwK2wl2ZdaUk8xjU5IHtV53hXGyAC6hAA4AXKCABlHwAnAEsAOwBzEABfGKYyEC9Q3AAvEncYoA) are not hard to come by.

Comment: Thanks @brhans - and apologies for the basic question

Comment: Do you know if there *should* be a buzzer on this board (does it beep?)  Something like this (cube with a hole in it) could also be an air pressure, gas, or humidity sensor.

Comment: @rdtsc - Yes it's an instrument board from a Nissan Leaf EV - which makes lots of annoying beeps from approximately this location :).  I was just wanting to make it a bit quieter - possibly with just some electric tape over the central hole to start with :)

Comment: Oh that's probably it then, give 'er a tape and see what happens. :)

Comment: @rdtsc: Sorry for not getting back to you!  It was the Piezo and the Leafs beeps are sooo much quieter now.  You can still hear them (which is what I was wanting) - just not as shrill.  Thank you for your help!